# SQL Server Joining the results of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to combine the result of two tables together, because when I am doing it separately, I get NULLS

This is the code I have

```
DECLARE @origSiteID int = 836,
    @NewSiteID int = 838


SELECT tblControls_Rooms.ID, @origSiteID
FROM tblControls_Rooms
WHERE SiteID = @OrigSiteID

SELECT tblControls_Rooms.ID, @NewSiteID
FROM tblControls_Rooms
WHERE SiteID = @newSiteID
```

WHEN I run it:

```
ID  (No column name)
1942    836
1943    836
1944    836
1945    836
1946    836
```

and

```
ID  (No column name)
2025    838
2026    838
2027    838
2028    838
```

I want the result to be:

```
ID  (No column name)
1942    836
1943    836
1944    836
1945    836
1946    836
2025    838
2026    838
2027    838
2028    838
```

Comment: Try Union.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Try `union all` unless mean to only retrieve distrinct records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Union would work, you could also use...

```
SELECT ID, SiteID
FROM tblControls_Rooms
WHERE SiteID IN (@OrigSiteID, @NewSiteID)
```

Comment: You don't need the equals sign in your last line :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(tblControls_Rooms.ID), tblControls_Rooms.SiteID
FROM tblControls_Rooms
WHERE SiteID = @OrigSiteID
OR SiteID = @newSiteID
```

You may not need the DISTINCT